# How do I update a value from one table in the second table every hour?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My site is a school web site.

The teacher choose every day a random student from the 'students' table, and update it in 'randoms' table.

Now I'm trying something else for making it easier.

I want the table 'randoms' will be updated every hour without the teacher, automatically.

it means that every hour, random student from the 'students' table will be updated in the 'randoms' table.

Is someone know how to do that?
thanks so much!!

Comment: If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done in mysql.

```
 CREATE EVENT update_random
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Updates Random Table with Student from Student Table every hour'
    DO 
    BEGIN
     UPDATE TABLE random SET student = (SELECT student FROM student ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
    END
```

There is some further information to enable disable the event scheduler in the mysql docs if you are having any issues with that working https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the host you can use `cron` to program a query which makes the task (assuming you are on linux). The query should be something like:

```sql
set @student = select name from student order by rand() limit 1;
update table randoms set student=@student;
```

And you can create the cron task issuing in the console `crontab -e` and adding a line like this:

```sh
0 */1 * * * mysql -u<user> -p<password> -D <database> -e "<sql command in one line>"
```

This will execute your query every hour. If you prefer executing it every 2 hours or more, just replace `*/1` for the desired period of time. If you are on Windows you can also run the sql using the Task Scheduler.

Comment: it can be done with mysql using the event scheduler.
have a read below
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html

Comment: Cool! But my answer will also work. Why downvoting? In fact in the article you can read: "Conceptually, this is similar to the idea of the Unix crontab (also known as a “cron job”) or the Windows Task Scheduler". Anyway I agree your answer is better because it resolves the problem only with MySQL.

Comment: The question wasnt how to do it in linux, i understand that you could do it in linux, but considering mysql has the capability. you should at least edit your post to remove the part saying it cant be done in mysql/phpmyadmin when it can.